# Invariant complementary sets modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, invariance

Let $p \ge 11$ be a prime number, $k,n$ be positive integers such that $n|gcd(p-1,k-1)$ and $p > k > n \ge 5$. Let $s \in \mathbb Z_p$ such that $ord_p(s) = n$. Is it possible that the sets $A = \{1,2,3,\dots,k-1\}$ and $B = \{k,k+1,k+2,\dots,p-1\}$ of classes modulo $p$ satisfy $sA = A$ and $sB = B$, simultaneously? I mean, are $A$ and $B$ invariants by multiplication by $s$?

Thanks!

Comment: In the case of $p=13$, $k=7$, $n=6$, and $s=4$, it is certainly not the case that $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $B=\{7,8,9,10,11,12\}$ are invariant under multiplication by $s$. Or are you asking if it's **ever** possible for this occur?

Comment: I think it is never possible that $A$ and $B$ are invariant, but I can not prove this.

Comment: Certainly, if there exist a counter-example, $n$ must be odd. In fact, if $n$ is even then $s^{n/2} \equiv -1 \pmod p$.

Comment: Now posted on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/q/247338/1916